# How to make image link in paragraph text in database driven UI

Tags: jquery, image, user-interface, text

how can i mark place in the text where i have to put image.

i am having a paragraph like whose contents comes from database

this is dummy text {show image1 here}. this is another dummy text {show image2 here}

and my images are stored in another table

is it possible that i put a map in text in the database so that i know where to display image

sorry for my bad English
Thanks for your precious time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use regular expressions to parse data like

```
<!--image--534--float:left-->
```

Extract ID from it, get actual image size and status.. and then replace with relevant HTML tag with applied styles. And its not only in decoding, but in encoding images from wysiwyg editor as well.

So simplified pseudocode in php roughly would be like...

```
preg_match_all('/\{[0-9]\}/i', $article, $matches);
foreach($matches as $imageTag){
str_replace('{'.$imageTag[0].'}','<img src="'.$imageTag[0].'.jpg" alt="" />');
}
```